# Activity not appearing on Chooser dialog when using Implicit Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I would like to start MyBrowser, an application that show web pages like the built-in Browser app, from another application, IntentsLab.

I followed [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) to setup the intent, and also [the official Intent and Intent-filters guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) which does says "You need to include CATEGORY_DEFAULT to receive implicit intents".

So my intent-filter is so written:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.categroy.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The code of the parent activity in IntentsLab to start the new activity is:

```
    Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    String title = "Use Browser";        
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, title);        
    if(chooserIntent != null)   startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

The MyBrowser application does not show up on the chooser dialog. However, when I created an Activity inside the IntentsLab and added to it a same intent-filter, this activity shows up in the chooser dialog. Is there anything wrong with the code? Or is there any difference between implicit intent towards Activities in a same Application with those in a different one?

Answer (score 2):

Provided my AndroidManifest.xml for the MyBrowserActivity.  It works perfectly for me.  Even I am doing the coursera Android programming class :)

```html
<activity android:name=".MyBrowserActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <!-- TODO - Add necessary intent filter information so that this
                    Activity will accept Intents with the
                    action "android.intent.action.VIEW" and with an "http"
                    schemed URL -->
</activity>
```